# View the content of C++ smart pointer array in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

For a raw pointer to an array in C++, the content of the **first N elements** can be seen by copying the expression into the Watch window of Visual Studio and appending a comma followed by the number of elements you want to see (for example: `testArray, 10`). How can the same memory content be seen in the Watch window when the array is created using a smart pointer? For example, if a unique_ptr is created via this statement:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> testArray = make_unique<int[]>(100)
```

How can we see the first 10 elements in the buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get()` method of smart pointer should be used : `testArray.get() , 10`

Answer (score 2):

Try this watch: `testArray._Mypair._Myval2, 10`

Comment: This is reliant on implementation details. It's kind of a textbook example of what _not_ to do, sorry ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, true, but this works whereas x.get(),10 does not.   `test.get(),10 Function std::unique_ptr<__int64 [0],std::default_delete<__int64 [0]> >::get has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.`